# Remove observations from a dataframe with pairwise comparison and multiple criteria

Tags: r

I need to selectively drop observations that based on pairwise comparisons of two variables with the rest of the dataset.

Specifically, these are cost effectiveness data and I want to drop 'dominated' interventions that where there exists an alternative that is 
1. More costly
2. Less effective

My example:

```
Township <- c(rep('A',3), rep('B',3))
Intervention <- rep(1:3, 2)
Cost <- c(1000, 500, 3000, 900, 1200, 1500)
Effect <- c(10, 8, 30, 10, 7, 8)  
Res <- data_frame(Township, Intervention, Cost, Effect)
```

Township A is the normal case where interventions and increasingly costly and increasingly effective
Township B contains 'dominated' interventions that are more costly and less effective than an alternative and need to be removed

The below is not scalable to larger dataset AND, for me, repeatedly crashes RStudio...!

```
Res.new <- Res %>% 
 group_by(Township) %>%
 arrange(Cost) %>%
 slice(-which(Effect<lag(Effect))[1], 
    -which(Effect<lag(Effect, k=2))[1]) # RStudio crashes
```

The solution I need is a data frame sorted by cost within each township
and excluding any example where there exists an alternative that is more costly and less effective

The result I am looking for:

```
Res.need <- Res %>% group_by(Township) %>% arrange(Cost)
Res.need <- Res.need[-c(5,6),]
```

In this case row 5 (B2) should be excluded since it is more costly and less effective than B1
Also row 6 (B3) should be excluded for the same reason, however lag-based solutions may get stuck as it is more effective than the previous example B2.

I think there is likely to be a better way using filter. I've searched for solutions but only found examples that filter based on comparisons with the dataset in general, rather than pairwise comparisons with two variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way using the **data.table** package, which is both simpler to read (the code I mean) and much faster and more scalable than the alternatives.

```
require(data.table)
Res.dt <- data.table(Res)
# figure out which intervention was least costly, within Township
Res.dt[, minCost := min(Cost), by = Township]
# get the Effect of the minimum cost intervention, within Township
Res.dt[, minCostEffect := Effect[Cost == minCost], by = Township][]
##    Township Intervention Cost Effect minCost minCostEffect
## 1:        A            1 1000     10     500             8
## 2:        A            2  500      8     500             8
## 3:        A            3 3000     30     500             8
## 4:        B            1  900     10     900            10
## 5:        B            2 1200      7     900            10
## 6:        B            3 1500      8     900            10
# select out the dominated observations
Res.dt[!(Cost > minCost & Effect < minCostEffect)][]
##    Township Intervention Cost Effect minCost minCostEffect
## 1:        A            1 1000     10     500             8
## 2:        A            2  500      8     500             8
## 3:        A            3 3000     30     500             8
## 4:        B            1  900     10     900            10
```

**ADDED:**

That's a vectorised solution but as you state in the new example in comments, it does not catch all the cases.  The problem is that within Township, we need a comparison of each intervention to all other interventions.  While normally we should avoid loops in R, this seems to call for it.  Since you did not mention speed in your question, just not blowing up R, this should still be okay.

```
# data with new examples
Res <- data.frame(Township = c(rep('A',3), rep('B',3), rep('C',3)),
                  Intervention = rep(1:3, 3), 
                  Cost = c(1000, 500, 3000, 900, 1200, 1500, 500, 600, 550),
                  Effect = c(10, 8, 30, 10, 7, 8, 5, 10, 11))
require(data.table)
Res.dt <- data.table(Res)

# function to find the dominated observations
findDominated <- function(data) {
    data.split <- split(Res.dt, Res.dt[, Township])
    dominated <- lapply(data.split, function(Res.subset) {
        domSplit <- logical(nrow(Res.subset))
        for (i in 1:nrow(Res.subset))
            domSplit[i] <- any(Res.subset$Cost[i] > Res.subset$Cost & Res.subset$Effect[i] < Res.subset[["Effect"]])
        domSplit
    })
    unlist(dominated, use.names = FALSE)
}
```

When applied to the new cases as defined in the data above, we now have the selection behaviour you desire, and the easy ability to select out these dominated cases and sort the result by Cost within Township:

```
Res.dt[, dominated := findDominated(Res.dt)][]
##    Township Intervention Cost Effect dominated
## 1:        A            1 1000     10     FALSE
## 3:        A            3 3000     30     FALSE
## 2:        A            2  500      8     FALSE
## 4:        B            1  900     10     FALSE
## 5:        B            2 1200      7      TRUE
## 6:        B            3 1500      8      TRUE
## 7:        C            1  500      5     FALSE
## 8:        C            2  600     10      TRUE
## 9:        C            3  550     11     FALSE

# sort by cost in each Township
setorder(Res.dt, Township, Cost)
# show non-dominated results
Res.dt[dominated == FALSE]
##    Township Intervention Cost Effect dominated
## 1:        A            2  500      8     FALSE
## 2:        A            1 1000     10     FALSE
## 3:        A            3 3000     30     FALSE
## 5:        C            1  500      5     FALSE
## 4:        B            1  900     10     FALSE
## 6:        C            3  550     11     FALSE
```

Comment: Very nice step-by-step explanation (even if the logic can be reduced into a single statement).

Comment: @Arun thanks! Can the minCost and minCostEffect creations be combined into a single statement?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @Ken. Actually I need to consider comparisons against all observations not only the observation with the minimum cost. An intervention is dominated if there exists some other observation where the cost is lower AND the effect is greater.

Comment: Township <- c(rep('C',3))
    Intervention <- 1:3
    Cost <- c(500, 600, 550)
    Effect <- c(5, 10, 11)
    Res <- data.frame(Township, Intervention, Cost, Effect)

Comment: An intervention could have a greater effect than the minCostEffect value but still be dominated by another intervention. Intervention 2 in the above is dominated by intervention 3, which is not the cheapest. Sorry for the multiple comments and poor formatting, I'm getting used to stackoverflow